# What does the phrase "developing proper driving habits" imply here? Actually what does "habits" refer to?

Tags: phrase-meaning

So today we want to talk about the subject of defensive driving. And the way I define defensive driving is, the ability **to develop the proper driving habits**, so that we can compensate for pretty much anything that goes on out on the roadways and that we can avoid a crash at any level.

Comment: *Habits* doesn't 'refer to' anything else here. Are you asking about what the word means? Have you looked it up in a  dictionary?

Answer (score 1):

[**Habit**](https://dictionary.reference.com/browse/habit) means:

> An acquired behavior pattern regularly followed until it has become almost involuntary

The writer is saying that the driving skills learnt will become automatic/instinctive behaviours.  The practices that the learner will be taught will become natural and will not require the learner to concentrate to keep doing them while driving.  This is good because if in the future something dangerous or sudden happens while driving, the learner will already know what to do and be able to automatically react to that situation rather than panicking.

Another way of saying this is that the driving skills that are learnt will become ['second nature'](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/second-nature).